# Difficulty including Armadillos library in mex file (Matlab + CPP) (error C2143 & error C2059 )

Tags: c++, matlab, armadillo

I am trying to modify some sample code of matlab showing use of mex file.

I tried to include armadillos library (http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html) without any success.

Though I did found one similar questions on this website; however, the answers were not helpful. So, I would appreciate some help.

I usually include armadillos **without any problem** as follows in my other visual C++ codes:

```
#define ARMA_64BIT_WORD
#include " C:\MIDEA\N4_VD13A_LATEST_20120616\n4\pkg\MrServers\MrImaging\seq\UserLib_DK\armadillo-3-910-0\include\armadillo"
using namespace arma;
```

However, when I do the same with “sincall.c”, it returns me error (multiple instances):

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\cstdlib(21) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before ':' 
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\cstdlib(21) : error C2059: syntax error : ':
```

My code looks like this:

```
#include "mex.h"
#define MAX 1000

//  #include armadillo
    #define ARMA_64BIT_WORD
    #include " C:\MIDEA\N4_VD13A_LATEST_20120616\n4\pkg\MrServers\MrImaging\seq\UserLib_DK\armadillo-3-910-0\include\armadillo"
    using namespace arma;

/* subroutine for filling up data */
void fill( double *pr, mwSize *pm, mwSize *pn, mwSize max )
{
    mwSize i;  
    /* you can fill up to max elements, so (*pr)<=max */
    *pm = max/2;
    *pn = 1;        // DK: it means that it's 1D array
    for (i=0; i < (*pm); i++) 
    {
      pr[i]=i*(4*3.14159/max);
    }
}


/* gateway function */
void mexFunction( int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[] )
{
    mwSize m, n, max=MAX;
    mxArray *rhs[1], *lhs[1];

    (void) nlhs; (void) plhs;    /* unused parameters */
    (void) nrhs; (void) prhs;

    rhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(max, 1, mxREAL);

    /* pass the pointers and let fill() fill up data */
    fill(mxGetPr(rhs[0]), &m, &n, MAX);
    mxSetM(rhs[0], m);
    mxSetN(rhs[0], n);


    /* get the sin wave and plot it */
    mexCallMATLAB(1, lhs, 1, rhs, "sin");
    mexCallMATLAB(0, NULL, 1, rhs, "plot");

    /* cleanup allocated memory */
    mxDestroyArray(rhs[0]);
    mxDestroyArray(lhs[0]);

    return;
}
```

First few lines of armadillos header file is:

```
#ifndef ARMA_INCLUDES
#define ARMA_INCLUDES


#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <climits>
#include <cmath>
```

Regards,
DK

Comment: Not the cause of the error, but that's a terrible way to include a library. Instead of hardcoding the absolute path to the include file, you should `#include <armadillo>` and then pass the directory path to that header to the `mex` command. `mex -I"C:/path/to/armadillo/header/file" mymexfile.c`. To figure out the cause of the error, look through the armadillo header. It's probably including `<cstdlib>` somewhere. Try looking at the definitions immediately before that include statement, maybe there's something defined that's incompatible with mex.

Comment: @Praetorian I added relevant lines from the header file of armadillo in my question. I still have no idea what may be going on wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't really have any further guesses into what might be going on. What's around line 21 within `cstdlib`?